# JavaScript not run on onsubmit event

Tags: javascript, html, onsubmit

To learn about web programming, I'm trying a simple html/javascript/php "product search" page. Here is the `index.php` file:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Product Search</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function mySubmit() {
                alert("submitting...");
                var product_type = $('product_type').value;
                $.post('product_search.php', { product_type: product_type }, function (data) {
                    alert("result = " + data); 
                    $('body').html(data);
                }
                return false;
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body id="body">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            mySubmit();
        </script>
        <form class="form" id="myform" method="post" onsubmit="javascript:return mySubmit();">
            Product Type:
            <input id="product_type" type="text" name="product_type"/>
            <br/><br/>
            <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

and the `product_search.php` file is very small:

```
<?php


$product_type = $_POST["product_type"];
echo "<h1>$product_type</h1>";

?>
```

The problem is that it seems like the `onsubmit` event is never called for the form. I thought it was a JavaScript problem (as in, not allowed to run), but if I run an `alert` instead of calling `mySubmit()` when the `onsubmit` event is called, it works!

Also, am I wrong in thinking that the JavaScript just under the `<body id="body">` should be run? It is never run either.

So, for those who didn't read all that: **why is my JavaScript function not being run when the `onsubmit` event is fired?**

Comment: Are you getting errors in the console? I would expect at least a `$ is undefined` based on your example.

Comment: Nope, no errors. Why should I get that error? Isn't `$` defined by jQuery to be `document.getElementById`?

Comment: where is your reference to jquery?

Comment: What do you mean? Isn't it referenced by default? I'm using xampp, if that helps.

Comment: nope .. you have to include it .. jquery is a library not available on its own.

Comment: @Guanxi ok, but I don't think that's the problem. JavaScript never gets around to executing that code anyway.

Comment: http://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/   alert is a javascript function and you can call it anyway ... but the function you have created includes jquery .. you need ot have jquery see the reference link

Comment: Not the problem, but as part of html5, you can omit `type="text/javascript"` from your `<script>` declarations.

Comment: You are also missing the closing `)` around your `$.post` call, so the function can't even be parsed correctly. I call BS on _no errors._

Comment: @Mathletics about the "BS on 'no errors'" I have not seen any errors yet. IE didn't tell me about any syntax errors in the JavaScript.

Comment: Well there's your problem right there; don't develop in IE, it hides the errors from you. Open the console in Chrome, Safari, Firefox, etc...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I get the following parsing errors when I run your code:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token return

Uncaught ReferenceError: mySubmit is not defined
```

You are missing the closing `)` on your `$.post` call, which is breaking the parser. Once you fix that, you'll get the `$ is undefined` error until you reference jQuery.

http://jsfiddle.net/Z6hJK/

Comment: You were right about the missing `);` - I added that, and now calling `mySubmit();` works! I didn't get the `$ is undefined` error, however... where would I see it?

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            mySubmit();
        </script>
```

above function is called but when it is called, even document.getElementById('product_type').value gives error (which might not be enabled on your browser to catch) as it product_type turn out to be null as javascript in body gets executed before browser has fully rendered the page. The moment it is getting called, product_type is not yet rendered.

On click also your function is getting called, but this time may be it is failing as you do not have reference to Jquery. include one.

Comment: "I would be thankful if somebody can explain it".. ah, no, the answer section is not the place to ask a question.

Comment: No need ... I have figured it out.